# Invalid date even if it's exactly the same

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I have following problem.

I have this function

```
  let time = datapoints.map((datapoint) => {
    let time = dayjs(datapoint.time)

    if (time.$d == 'Invalid Date') {
      console.log(datapoint.time, 'invalid')
    } else {
      console.log(datapoint.time)
    }
    return time
  })
```

`datapoint.time` is in this format `12.1.2021, 22:45:00`

Now if i console log it, it displays me:

[image]

I dont get it, why does it just kind of randomly does not convert this time?

EDIT:

I tried following:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat'
let time = dayjs(datapoint.time, 'DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm:ss')
```

But its still invalid date

Comment: Is it expecting MM/DD/YYYY format? 13 wouldn't be a valid month.

Comment: @DBS well, it should be DD/MM/YYYY, but yea this could be the problem

Comment: @DBS how do i tell dayjs that the incoming format is in DD/MM/YYYY and not MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with the library, but they seem to have some [documentation here](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format) that might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, change `let time = dayjs(datapoint.time, 'DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm:ss')` to `let time = dayjs(datapoint.time, 'DD.M.YYYY, HH:mm:ss')` as MM expects 2 digit month and you have 1 digit month.

For anyone stumbling across:
https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format#list-of-all-available-parsing-tokens

Comment: Yes i see. It only worked after i  changed `DD` to `D` too